# Python - Check if variable was given to function or was used the default one

Tags: python

I have a function that uses a datetime object as default value:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

def getTime(date = datetime.now()):
    i = randint(1,300)
    date = date - timedelta(seconds = i) 
    return date
```

Now, I need to check if the date variable inside the function was given by another function or was used the default one datetime.now(). If was used the default one, then subtract i seconds, else return the date that was given.

Comment: Your code calculates the default time once when the script is loaded. Is that what you want or do you want the time recalculated on each call?

Comment: I just flagged it as unclear until this point gets cleared

Comment: Hyperion: please answer @tdelaney question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
def my_function(date=None):
    if date is None:
        # The default is used
        date = datetime.now()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want "now" to be computed every time:

```
def getTime(date=None):
    return date or datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=randint(1,300))
```

Otherwise:

Introduce a default arg:

```
def getTime(date=None, _default=datetime.now()):
        return date or _default - timedelta(seconds=randint(1,300))
```

Or create a decorator:

```
def just_return_if_provided(f):
    def inner(date=None):
        return date or f(date)
    return inner

@just_return_if_provided
def getTime(date=datetime.now()):
    return date - timedelta(seconds=randint(1,300))
```

Comment: That's not the same thing. In the original code, you only get a single datetime at the point the script was compiled.

Comment: The accepted answer also does the same "mistake" then. If this has to be a default param, then the only way is to write a decorator which would return the date if provided or just invoke the decorated function if not.

Comment: @tdelaney I just added another solution to handle this scenario

Comment: I added a question for the poster hoping for clarification... but no response yet!